# In which bag laptop charger and laptop battery can be taken? And in which bag food can be taken?

Tags: airports

Can I carry my laptop battery and charger on my check in luggage? And  is food like fried rice and mutton can be carried to carry on baggage?

Comment: Which countries, which airline? Do you want to take the food into the destination country or is it just to eat on the plane?

Answer (score 1):

That depends a bit on the airline and specific route. Check with the airline to make sure.

In general food, laptop batteries and laptops can go into carry on luggage.

Spare lithium ion batteries can often NOT go into checked luggage must be taken into carry on https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/more_info/?hazmat=7

Many countries do not allow food to go into the country, so you need to eat it on the airplane or throw it away when arriving (internationally).

If you decide to bring food on the plane, please be mindful of your fellow passengers: Anything that's messy or can be smelled should be avoided. Economy class seats have very little space: Picking something that's easy to eat and easy to clean up afterwards may be an advantage. Sandwiches, snack bars, apples, etc work well. Fried rice and mutton may not be the best idea.